# Unable to replicate Angular: Tour of heroes search behaviour, problem with Observers

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular9

I'm trying to implement a searchbar with autocomplete suggestions in Angular 9, it worked in the tour of heroes tutorial but when I try to replicate it, the searchTerms pipe does nothing (service is never called).

I checked the observers of searchTerms in the tour of heroes app and immediately after creation it already has one observer. 
In my App however this is not the case, so the main question is: when does the searchTerms in the tour of heroes App get its observer?

**this works, service is called**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

import {
  debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap
} from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-search',
  templateUrl: './hero-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './hero-search.component.css' ]
})
export class HeroSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes$: Observable<Hero[]>;
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {}

  // Push a search term into the observable stream.
  search(term: string): void {
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // one observer
    console.log(this.searchTerms.observers);
    this.heroes$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
      // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
      debounceTime(300),

      // ignore new term if same as previous term
      distinctUntilChanged(),

      // switch to new search observable each time the term changes
      switchMap((term: string) => this.heroService.searchHeroes(term)),
    );
  }
}
```

**this doesn't**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, Subject} from "rxjs";
import {SearchService} from "../search.service";
import {debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap} from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  suggestions$: Observable<string[]>;
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService) {}

  search(value: string): void {
    this.searchTerms.next(value);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // 0 Observers, service from pipe is never called
    console.log(this.searchTerms.observers);
    this.suggestions$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),

      distinctUntilChanged(),

      switchMap((term: string) => this.searchService.getSuggestions(term)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your `suggestions$` subscribed anywhere?

Comment: I think we need the html also

Comment: i forgot to subscibe to suggestions$ in the html file with '*ngFor="let suggestion of suggestions$ | async"' , it works now, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you haven't subscribed to the `suggestion$` observable, that's why the values emitted by it are not used anywhere resulting in no feedback.

Comment: yeah, that was the problem. As mentioned in my comment above, I forgot to subscribe to the suggestions$ in the html file, marking this as the solution in case anyone forgets it too, thank you

Comment: Ahh. I haven't looked at comments. As I got the answer, I done that .